# Extract google sheet data to a Word template

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm creating weekly reports and the data all come from a google sheet with the same format. Instead of entering the data manually in the word file. I created a Word template and want to import the data automatically from the google sheet to my Word template.

My Word template looks like:

[image]
The bolded data in the Word file come from the "New" column. The green/red data in the Word file come from "Diff" column.

[image]

I know how to get these data from the google sheet using Pandas, but I want to know how should I place them in the specific area in my word template.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about it would be to go from Google Sheet -> Google Doc and take advantage of the native integration there. From there you can just export it as a .docx file or something and it should be openable in Word as well. I did this exact thing a while back, so it's definitely doable (if not easier now) but [here's a place to start](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/).